# Custom predicates for custom items in Minecraft don't work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I have created a custom resource pack and model using Blockbench, now I want to have a custom texture for a gold nugget with certain custommodeldata but when I enable the resource pack and load in game, it doesn't show. It is still a gold nugget.

Contents of my folder: (im on version 1.15.2)

pack

- pack.mcmeta:

```
{
    "pack": {
        "pack_format": 5,
        "description": "Test pack"
    }
}
```

- assets:

  - minecraft:

    - models:

      - customstick.json:

```
{
    "credit": "Made with Blockbench",
    "texture_size": [32, 32],
    "textures": {
        "0": "custom/sticknugget",
        "particle": "custom/sticknugget"
    },
    "elements": [
        {
            "from": [7, 0, 0],
            "to": [9, 1, 16],
            "rotation": {"angle": 0, "axis": "y", "origin": [16, 8, 8]},
            "faces": {
                "north": {"uv": [0, 0, 1, 0.5], "texture": "#0"},
                "east": {"uv": [0, 0, 0.9995, 8], "texture": "#0"},
                "south": {"uv": [0, 0, 1, 0.5], "texture": "#0"},
                "west": {"uv": [0, 0, 0.999, 8], "texture": "#0"},
                "up": {"uv": [0, 0, 1, 8], "texture": "#0"},
                "down": {"uv": [0, 0, 1, 8], "texture": "#0"}
            }
        }
    ],
    "display": {
        "thirdperson_righthand": {
            "rotation": [100, 0, 90],
            "translation": [-7, 4.75, 2.5]
        },
        "firstperson_righthand": {
            "translation": [0, 8.5, 0]
        },
        "firstperson_lefthand": {
            "translation": [0, 8, 0]
        }
    }
}
```

```
    - gold_nugget.json:
```

```
{
 "parent": "item/handheld",
 "textures": {
  "layer0": "item/gold_nugget"
 },

 "overrides": [
  {"predicate": {"custom_model_data": 888765}, "model": "item/model"}
  {"predicate": {"custom_model_data": 5555}, "model": "item/customstick"}
 ]
}
```

And then in assets/minecraft/textures/custom I have a customstick.png texture file. Where exactly is the problem? This is the command I'm using for getting the item:
`/give @p gold_nugget{CustomModelData:5555,customitem:1b} 1`

I also have made textures/entity/creeper and it works in game, why doesn't this work? I followed an online guide for this

Answer (score 0):

Add a folder in the models folder and name it 'item' and then put the models in the item folder.  That should help.  For more help on custommodeldata watch the following video.